# How to use the Riemannian metric to compute an integral?

Tags: integration, riemannian-geometry, lp-spaces, tensor-products, riemann-surfaces

If i am using a Riemannian metric on the cone $C$ with conical point at origin and metric given by $dt^2 +t^2d\phi^2$ with $t>0$ and $\phi\in (0,2\pi )$ how to use this to do an integral. For example, for the function $f(t,\phi)=t^{\frac{1}{2}\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{k^2}{a}}}\cos\phi$ i want to find conditions such that $f\in L^2(C)$. So, my attempt is

$$f\in L^2\leftrightarrow \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(t,\phi)|^2 dtd\phi$$

but how can i use the terms $dt^2 +t^2d\phi^2$ on the integral above? I mean if i applied power two in the integrand then $1\pm2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{k^2}{a}}\cos^2\phi$ but $\cos\phi$ is bounded and the important term is $t^{1+2\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{k^2}{a}}}$ but how to associate with the coefficient $1$ of $dt^2$ and the coefficient $t^2$ of $d\phi^2$? I know that the matrix that represent the metric $g$ is
\begin{array}{}
1\quad0\\0\quad t^2
\end{array}
But to be honest i do know how we use it when we need to do an integral. Please, somebody can help me? or give me one reference to read with examples.

Comment: There's actually not a cone point at the origin. This is just ("flat") polar coordinates on the plane. But your integral should be — as you expect from polar coordinates — $t\,dt\,d\phi$. (Think of $dx^2+dy^2$ turning into $dx\,dy$; $dt^2+t^2\,d\phi^2$ turns into $(dt)(t\,d\phi)$.)

Comment: Dear @TedShifrin i appreciate your answer but what happen with the Riemannian metric, is like if we don need it? Thank you

Comment: I *did* use it. Did you read what I wrote?

Comment: Now i read, thank you again!!!

Comment: You're welcome. In more dimensions, if your metric is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_i(x)^2 dx_i^2$, then the volume element will be $\lambda_1(x)\dots\lambda_n(x)dx_1\dots dx_n$ (assuming all $\lambda_i>0$).

Comment: thank you Dear @TedShifrin